# Volume Low in Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-8.1, volume-mixer

Volume for audio and video sounds too quiet in Chrome, e.g. on YouTube. I have tried restarting it (via the actual exit option) and then I tried restarting the computer.

Running Windows 8.1.

Volume mixer looks normal.

Comment: Could be a botched audio driver installation. Re-install the audio driver and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If it's a hardware issue, you can boost the volume up to 6x via this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-master/jghecgabfgfdldnmbfkhmffcabddioke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the steps for the volume issue in Google Chrome, on Windows OS:

1. Open a new google chrome browser.
2. Open the webpage by typing "chrome://plugins"
3. Now click "+details" towards the right side of the screen.
4. Disable the "\PepperFlash\Pepperflashplayer.dll"
5. Let the "\Macromed\Flash\" be enabled.

Change these settings and check for the volume

Comment: this is clearly overkill when @RockPaperLizard's answer is almost certainly the fix

Comment: @Simon I interpreted "Volume mixer looks normal" as indicating that it's not a Windows volume control issue. I have the same problem, any audio in Chrome is about 50% softer than in Firefox or IE, although that extends to HTML5 audio and video, so for me neither answer was a solution.

Comment: This answer no longer works in Chrome.

Comment: @Dorian indeed. I am using Windows 10 and Google Chrome playback sound was really low. I have increased sound volume and it did not help. But now sound is high again on my speakers: for now the only way to increase sound volume was to enable "Loudness Equalization". You guys can try Sound-> Playback->Speakers->Properties->Enhancements->Loudness Equalization

Comment: @JuniorM thanks for the workaround - that did it for me - I'd tried a few of the others, but for some reason hadn't tried that one. Seems like an odd solution, but works for now!

Answer (score 22):

To turn up the volume in Chrome:

1. Start playing sound in Chrome (e.g. Music or YouTube)
2. Click volume icon in taskbar
3. Click Mixer
4. Adjust the volume level for Chrome.
5. If you raise it to the Speaker volume, they should become linked.

Comment: For Windows 10, right-click the volume icon to see the "Open Volume mixer" button.

Answer (score 10):

In Windows7, go to `Sounds`→`Playback`.
For Windows10, search for and select `Manage Audio Devices`.

Pick speakers as output device and go into its `Properties`.
At the `Levels` tab, check if is set at 100%.
If it was, go to the `Enhancements` tab, and enable `Loudness Equalisation`.

Comment: this is the best answer, though there are no properties in "Manage Audio Devices" anymore, it has to be done from the Sound tab. But enabling "Loudness Equalisation" definitely solved my problem with low volume, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Open chrome browser:

- Go to `Start` > `Search` and type `vol`.
- Click on `Adjust system volume`.

You should see a volume slider specifically for Google Chrome (this only shows up if the browser is currently open).

Test volume in browser - adjust Chrome setting:

[image: Volume Mixer]

Comment: A thousand thank yous!  I had no idea that windows had application specific volume controls build into the volume mixer.  Wow!  That was my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue but in Windows 10 (only with Chrome videos e.g. YouTube, despite volume set to max in the Volume Mixer), tried all the solutions here and the one with restarting the Windows Audio service worked! 
So "Computer Management", "Services and Applications", "Services" and restart "Windows Audio". 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems only with Youtube Video on Google Chrome or overall system? There are a few ways to increase the volume of the system. One method that I like is using the loudness equalization in Windows which doesn't require any tool. Here's the step by step instructions:
Click on the Volume icon in the system tray
Click on the speaker icon on the sound mixer popup Sound Mixer
Select Enhancements from the opened window
Check Loudness Equalization from the list and click OK

[This article](http://www.itechtics.com/increase-maximum-volume-windows-8/) explains other methods too but first try the one I have listed here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Windows 8, and I solved using the following steps:

1. Right click on start and select "Computer Management".
2. Double click in "Services and Applications".
3. Double click in "Services".
4. Search for the Service "Windows Audio".
5. Select "Windows Audio" and press "Restart".