# windows sound changing randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, debug

I'm not sure whats going on but recently my windows sound keeps changing even though mixer volume stays the same. For example, i'll be watching youtube videos with normal volume and then click on a new video and the volume is all the sudden quiet even though I haven't actually changed the volume and slider is in the same position in both windows and youtube. I tried re-installing drivers and everything. Every time this happens, I have to close the tab i'm on or open a new browser in order to make the volume go back to normal. Please please help, this is so annoying.

---

seems like it's only happening in chrome, i'm testing in explorer right now and volume is staying the same so far every time I change to a new video

Comment: Another example, once I click a new video and volume goes low, I can open a new "tab" in the same browser with normal volume so 2 different volumes in 1 opened chrome

Comment: This sounds like a browser or browser plugin problem, not a windows or driver problem.  Have you tried opening your browser with all plugins disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall chrome and then install it again and check if your issue is resolved.

Or Open chrome settings > Advanced > Reset and Cleanup > Restore settings to their original defaults.

Also try this :When chrome is open> Right click speaker icon and then Open volume mixer. Bring all sliders to the same level(linked).

Comment: check this link also
https://superuser.com/questions/840643/volume-low-in-chrome-browser